# ASP.NET not providing more than one server side form

Tags: asp.net

what's the philosophy behind that ASP.NET does not allow to make more than one form with the tag `runat=server` ...

Comment: Duplicate of [Why you can't have a page with multiple server-side Form tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360270/why-you-cant-have-a-page-with-multiple-server-side-form-tags). Found this after answering.

Answer (score 2):

Web Forms are built—for better or worse—around concepts meant to abstract the underlying platform. Server controls, server events, ViewState and UpdatePanels are examples of this approach.

Multiple forms aren't impossible, but would be unintuitive for the novice developer who adds server controls to his/her page and wants them to "just work". For an experienced developer, it would be nice, but it would introduce a new set of caveats (and Web Forms have *many* nuances and caveats).

For example, let's say I added a `GridView` to form A, and a `DropDownList` to form B. The drop down triggers a postback, but only the data in form B is posted to the server (that's how forms work; only one gets posted at a time).

However, the GridView is now missing all its ViewState, which was contained in form A. The page is now completely broken.

Ad hoc ViewState values are even more tricky. The developer can put whatever they want into ViewState as a name/value pair. How should the server decide which form gets the ViewState? if it goes into *all* forms, that's page bloat.

**Summary**

- It's not technically impossible, but the problems potentially outweigh the benefits.
- There are means by which you can add a second `<form>` to an ASPX page (though it may not run at the server).
- There is absolutely nothing wrong with multiple forms on a page. This is one of the many advantages to working with the platform instead of fighting/abstracting it, such as ASP.Net MVC attempts to do.